# redux form validation - Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Tags: validation, reactjs, console, runtime-error, redux-form

I am getting this error in the console :

```
Cannot read property 'some' of undefined     hasError.js:32
```

The validation function :

```
export const validateFields = values => {
  let errors = {};
  errors.name = "Required";
  return errors;
}

reduxForm({
    form: "AppForm",
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    validate: validateFields,
    onSubmit: () => {}
})
```

When I have plain error object, no errors in the console, but when I add, this weird error shows up.

Do you know, what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `when i have plain error object, i have no error in console, but when i add, this weird error shows up.` what does this mean ? Also, can you share the rest of your component code, and `hasError.js` ?

Comment: I solved this issue. I was registering fields by actions creators, and i didnt provided third parameter - type - "Field". Addit this third parameter helped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. I was registering fields by actions creators, and I didn't provide the third parameter - i.e. `type - "Field"`. Adding this third parameter helped.